# How can I copy to the clipboard an attribute or method name from the PyDev package explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

How can I copy to the clipboard an attribute or method name from the PyDev package explorer in Eclipse?

For example, if I select the attribute `self.label_indices`, I would like to have a way to copy it to the clipboard (e.g. with a keyboard shortcut or through the context menu):

[image]

Context menu:

[image]

Comment: What's shown in the context menu?

Comment: @nitind context menu added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's seems this is currently not possible.

I.e.: you have to actually open it and then copy from the editor -- there you can copy only the text or full qualified name (from the context menu).

You can create a feature request for this at https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/ (although even better would be providing a pull request :) -- see: http://www.pydev.org/developers.html)